# ¿Son correctas tanto "transporte" como "transportación"? ¿Y "aporte" - "aportación"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Para mí la forma correcta de esta palabra es "transporte", pero dado que muchas veces escucho "transportación", me hace preguntarme si también está bien dicho.

Otro ejemplo de esto sería "aporte (tación)". Hasta donde sé, se usan ambas para referirse a lo mismo.

¿Están ambas bien dichas? También está la variación "trasportamiento", o "aportamiento", pero estas variantes (¿variaciones?) no serían unas que yo usaría normalmente.

Comment: ¿Dónde vives, o dónde escuchas estas palabras habitualmente?

Answer (score 4):

*[Transportación](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=aMdGe3p)* es una palabra correcta, pero desusada, porque es sinónima casi exacta de *transporte* en su uso más común. Me extraña que la hayas escuchado con frecuencia. Lo mismo ocurre con *aporte*. En lo personal nunca he escuchado *transportación* ni *aportación*. ¿Puede ser que *transportación* sea un calco sobre el inglés *transportation*?

Lo mismo ocurre con *transportamiento* y *aportamiento*: existen, pero no son frecuentes en el uso real. Personalmente no veo ninguna razón para utilizarlas ya que son derivaciones de sus sinónimos exactos que no aportan ninguna connotación extra.

Comment: Curiosamente, a pesar de casi exclusivamente escuchar *transporte*, yo sí escucho *aportación* un pelín más que *aporte* (aunque escucho ambas formas).

Comment: En realidad debería haber preguntado de que región estamos hablando. Veré si puedo comprobar la frecuencia de uso por algún medio.

Comment: If it is relevant to your comment about the English transportation i think that is more common in the US so i would expect Hispanophone countries more influenced by proximity to the US to use it more. We shall doubtless see.

Comment: Theia es de Cuba: [¿Quiénes somos?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2587/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui de hecho he visto que lo haz usado varias veces. Se usa mucho en Espana de esta forma?

Comment: En mexico se usa mucho más **aportación** ya que es el término referido por el [IMSS](www.imss.gob.mx) para los pagos al instituto

Comment: En España es mas común aportación que aporte

Comment: En España yo he leído o escuchado indistintamente tanto **aportación** como **aporte**. pero jamás he leído **transportación**, salvo en el caso de **teletransportación**.